# Springboot and manage many parallels Rest calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i want to create a microservice in Springboot that calls (with Feign client or WebClient) other rest microservices.

For Example:

GET Detail Product microservices

```
Feign remote sub-call number 1 for user data dto response
Feign remote sub-call number 2 for contract data dto response
Feign remote sub-call number 3 for registry office data dto response
```

if only one of this sub-calls response with http error (500-502...), the microservice response with ko.

What is best practice and the powerfull library for manage this case? RxJava?

Thank you
Alex

Comment: what is "ko"? can you explain

Comment: @Mansoor Service or Custom Exception

Comment: I didn't got your real problem but I think if even your feign remote return 5xx you need manage your microservices to throw exceptions to response and customize the code response

Comment: @Dilermando Lima Yes ok but is there a library that manage multi rest calls?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with my current task.

Here is my simple solution.

ExecutorService

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

I write my own worker to do sub-call and handle result/error in each worker.

You can write your worker by implement Runnable or Callable which is depend on your purpose.

If any errors in worker, i decide to return error code (5xx) ... or timeout ...

Otherwise, the service is OK.